# Requiring grape hugely slows down Goliath

Tags: ruby, grape-api, goliath

I've written a 'Hello World' app using `Goliath`, and I decided to mount `Grape` on top of it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.setup :default
require 'goliath'
require 'grape'   # <-- Comment out this line will hugely increase performance, but why?

class Server < Goliath::API
  def response(env)
    [200, {}, 'Hello, world!']
  end
end
```

I benchmarked it:

```
ab -n 1000 -c 100 http://localhost:9000/
```

It shows that about 250 requests can be handled per second. But when I comment out the line `require 'grape'`, this value suddenly increased to about 700. Can anybody answer why the simple `require` can bring such a huge difference?

P.S. I use MRI 2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Goliath in production mode? You have to set -e prod of it will do code re-loading on each request.